# Binding CSS3 Gradient Styles in Knockout.js

Tags: knockout.js

I have come across a problem that I am not sure how to deal with regards to style binding.

My ViewModel object contains two properties, HexColor1 and HexColor2. I am trying to bind these properties to a background image gradient style.

Example of the resulting HTML I need (where HexColor1 = "#FFFFFF" and HexColor2 = "#000000"):

```
<div style="background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #FFFFFF, #000000); background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #FFFFFF, #000000);">Hello</div>
```

What is the best way to do this? Should I create computed properties that contain all the *-linear-gradient style strings or is there a way to do it directly in the style binding?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The real question is why not use style sheets and seperate content and layout?

Oh well, if you really need to set them dynamically

A computed isnt very good because you inject View dependencies into your ViewModel, why not make a gradient custom binding that takes the the two colors?

Comment: I am not using a static stylesheet for this because the hex values are dynamically set by the user and pulled from the database.

Comment: Okey, then I would go with a custom binding